# adding media queries from js

Tags: javascript, css

I have a page where I open a new window  like so

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=755.9100,height=347.7200");
myWindow.document.body.append(img);
```

I want to add styles some style to this new window from the previous window

```
@page {size: A4;margin: 0;@media print {html, body {width: 210mm;height: 297mm;}
```

How do I add this to head tag in html through js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is the [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) function in js:

The usage is quite simple:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
    /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
    /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

One more useful article is [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-media-queries/).

Comment: This only works for on load. The correct answer would have a rendered media query that would respond to window size changes on the fly.

Answer (score 3):

`style` is also an HTML element, so you can append that in a similar manner as you are appending the img element

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=755.9100,height=347.7200");
myWindow.document.body.append(img);
var style = myWindow.document.createElement("style")
style.innerHTML = "@page {size: A4;margin: 0;@media print {html, body {width: 210mm;height: 297mm;}"
myWindow.document.head.append(style);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that checking [`MediaQueryList.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches) does not actually add a media query to the CSS. You have to run this check every time the window changes. To do this, you should call [`addListener(callback)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/addListener) on the [`MediaQueryList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) in addition to checking the [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList/matches) property directly.

For example, to apply your style to the `<html>` and `<body>` elements on printed pages:

```
let mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia("print");
function screenTest(e) {
    if (e.matches) {
        document.documentElement.style.width = "210mm";
        document.body.style.width = "210mm";
        document.documentElement.style.width = "297mm";
        document.body.style.width = "297mm";
    }
    else {
        document.documentElement.style.width = null;
        document.body.style.width = null;
    }
}
screenTest(mediaQueryList);
mediaQueryList.addListener(screenTest);
```